# UIAccess and Elevation without using the secure desktop

Tags: .net, windows, uac, local-security-policy

I am writing a remote desktop software similar to VNC and wanted to capture UAC prompts by leveraging functionalities given by UIAccess permission and Security policies.

**Theory:**

As per below given MSDN blogs, you need to set "Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Allow UIAccess applications to prompt for elevation without using the secure desktop" property to "Enabled" in order to allow applications with 'UIAccess' permission to make the 'UAC prompt' to be displayed on user interactive desktop instead of secure desktop.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2009/01/08/helpdesk-elevation-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2009/10/15/using-the-uiaccess-attribute-of-requestedexecutionlevel-to-improve-applications-providing-remote-control-of-the-desktop/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asklar/2012/03/14/remote-assistance-and-uac-prompts/

**Observation:**
I wrote a program with the below given code.

```
static void Main()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    p.Start();
}
```

Then I added the following to app.manifest

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true" />
```

Then I self signed the application as per the [MSDN forum instructions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/350ceab8-436b-4ef1-8512-3fee4b470c0a/problem-with-manifest-and-uiaccess-set-to-true?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues).

Then I manually copied the program to a subfolder in Program Files (x86) folder.

Then I enabled "Allow UIAccess applications to prompt for elevation without using the secure desktop" security policty.

When I run the program (in the same system where i generated certificate), I expected the UAC prompt to be shown in user's interactive desktop. But it is still running in 'secure desktop' even though the application invoked it has UIAccess permission.

What might have went wrong?

Comment: Hi @Artic, did you manage to solve this issue? Do you have an app to showcase this scenario? I'm interested in remote support software that runs without elevated permissions by default but has an option to elevate some program if needed by using LAPS temporary admin account.

Answer (score 1):

The `uiAccess` feature is extraordinarily dangerous. Because of this, Windows will only honor it if:

- the application is digitally signed, and
- is located in one of the trusted locations *e.g. C:\Program Files*